# fl_chart error the getter 'touchinput' isn't defined for the type 'FlTouchEvent'

Tags: flutter, dart, fl-chart

While working on a flutter app to implement the pie chart from fl_chart package, I got the following error when I tried to run the program:

> the getter 'touchinput' isn't defined for the type 'FlTouchEvent'. Try importing the library that defines 'touchInput', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'touchInput' <

**Code Snippet of implementation**

```
class _ActivityPieChartState extends State<ActivityPieChart> {
  int _touchIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 25,
      child: Card(
        color: Colors.black,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18)),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 60,
              child: PieChart(
                PieChartData(
                  borderData: FlBorderData(show: false),
                  //This is to make chart interactive when user touches areas of the chart
                  pieTouchData: PieTouchData(
                    touchCallback: (pieTouchResponse) {
                      setState(() {
                        if (pieTouchResponse.touchedSection is FlLongPressEnd ||
                            pieTouchResponse.touchedSection is FlPanEndEvent) {
                          _touchIndex = -1;
                        } else {
                          _touchIndex = pieTouchResponse.touchedSectionIndex;
                        }
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

how would I be able to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Here toughCallback function takes two arguments (FlTouchEvent,PieTouchResponse) since you are not using FltouchEvent you can give underscore as your first argument (_).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).